# whaen i am sending mail to any mail id that message has to go that mail id with out asking email client on android

Tags: android

Hi when i am sending a mail to particular mail id from my apllication that mail has to send to that mail id with out asking email client in android? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you can't, unless you get the user's authorization to control her gmail acount: https://developers.google.com/accounts/